# Custom subscribe button

Tags: web-push, push-api, pushpad

I would like to customize the subscribe button and add it to my website, how can I do that?

Currently users can subscribe to push notifications using this link:
https://pushpad.xyz/p/3898

Answer (score 0):

You have different options.

## Option 1 - Use Pushpad Express with ui=false

I think that the easiest way is to create a button on your website and use the `ui=false` option as described here:
https://pushpad.xyz/docs/pushpad_express_without_ui

For example [create a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link) with this link on your website:

```
https://pushpad.xyz/p/YOUR_PROJECT_ID?ui=false
```

**NOTE**: I've noticed that you use a legacy version of Pushpad, which unfortunately doesn't support the ui=false option. In order to use the ui=false option you need to create a new sender (and select Pushpad Express) and then create a new project associated to the new sender.

## Option 2 - Use Pushpad Pro

Otherwise, if you don't want to redirect the user to a Pushpad subdomain, you can use Pushpad Pro:
https://pushpad.xyz/docs/pushpad_pro_getting_started

Also see the "Button" example on this page: https://pushpad.xyz/docs/javascript_sdk_examples